# Write $f(x) =x^3+x^2-3x-3$ as a product of a linear factor and a quadratic factor

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I know that the linear factor is $(x+1) (x^2-3),$ but how would I find the quadratic factor?

Comment: That factor is not linear - I assume you're referring to **just** $(x+1)$ being the linear factor?

Comment: Also, the title seems to imply that you're trying to write this as a product of multiple quadratic factors. You would only have one quadratic factor at most (unless you want to get into some really messy computations that I imagine are far beyond what the question intends).

Comment: You need \$ to delimit math expressions.  I've fixed for you, but it's considered a courtesy to your fellow users to learn to do it yourself.  I think you've already solved your own problem.  The quadratic factor is $x^2-3$.

Comment: Um... Its $x^2 -3$....

Comment: Yes the original question on my paper said to write f(x) as a product of a linear factor and a quadratic factor, I got how to write the linear factor part but I don’t know how the quadratic factor can be done

Answer (score 2):

It is a polynomial of degree 3, and it is the product of the quadratic factor $x^2-3$ and the linear factor $x+1$. But maybe I miss your point.

Answer (score 1):

Simply calculate the roots of your polynomial (if possible).
You have a polynomial of degree 3. 
Normally you first try to find a root, by "guessing". We have to check the divesors of the constant -3. Which are $\pm 3, \pm 1$.

Easily we see, that x=-1 is a root and then make a long division

$(x^3+x^2-3x-3)\div (x+1)$ giving us the quadratic factor.

On other way is to compare coefficients by:

$(x^3+x^2-3x-3)=(ax+b)(cx^2+dx+e)$

Which should involve more calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Horner's algorithm* for the division by $x+1$:
\begin{array}{r|rrrr}
&1&1&-3&-3\\
\times -1&\downarrow&\nearrow -1&0&3\\
\hline
&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}{-3}&0
\end{array}
so the quotient is $\;x^2+ 0\mkern 1.5mux-3=x^2-3$.

Comment: You mean $x^2-3?$

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing the typo!